# How to make a jQuery modal box display "on top" of page elements?

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog, css

I'm currently developing a small jQuery popup modal box. I am using the `toggleSlide()` function which works well. However whenever I call the box it pushes all of the other content out of the way.

I've tried using `position: relative;` and `display: inline;` for CSS properties, but neither has worked.

Would love some insight from anybody who can help. You can view the code live on my demo site here: [REMOVED] Sorry but this demo was taken offline!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to `.containmsg` and then set your modal box to `position:absolute` adjusting the figures slightly to line it up perfectly.

```
.containmsg {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}

.containmsg .mainComposeD {
    left: -33px;
    position: absolute; /* add this */
    top: 22px; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: you are a life saver thank you! I didn't really understand positioning for these modal boxes. It took me a minute, but very simple. thanks also for using the same classes made it way easier